# IllegalArgumentException in byte[] to image conversion java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, illegalargumentexception

I am using a database which has images stored in it as byte[]. 
I have written this function to get images from a byte[] data.
The fileName is correct and data is not null.

```
public void convert(String fileName , byte[] data) throws IOException
    {   
    File myFile =  new File(fileName);
    System.out.println("filename is " + file);
    ByteArrayInputStream baisData = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    BufferedImage imag= ImageIO.read(baisData);
    if(imag == null)
    {
        System.out.println("imag is empty");
    }
    ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", myFile);
    System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
}
```

But when I run this code, I am getting this output.

```
filename is C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\Eclipse\try\i1.jpg
imag is empty
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
  at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
  at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
  at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
  at TempConvert.convert(TempConvert.java:32)
  at TempConvert.main(TempConvert.java:60)
```

Please tell me what might be reason behind 'imag' object being null and what should I do to run my code perfectly.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What format are the `byte[]` coming from the DB?  If JPEG, you should be able to write the `byte[]` directly to disk as a JPEG (without using `ImageIO`).

Comment: Its jpg format.
The database actually contains images uploaded by different users. The whole code for the website is written in C#. But I know only java. Can the use of C# for data entry in databse and java for data extraction be the cause of my problem?

System.Web.HttpPostedFile userfile;
int fileSize = userfile.ContentLength;
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[fileSize];   userfile.InputStream.Read(fileBuffer,0,fileSize);

Comment: There's "nothing wrong" with your code, the problem is that `ImageIO.read` will return `null` if you pass data it does not recognize. However, if you know the database contains JPEG images and you want to output JPEG images, why do you want to decode the JPEG image in Java, just to encode it again? Just dump the database contents to disk. Then you'll also find out if other programs are able to decode the data, and verify if it's really JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you know `data` contains JPEG data, and you want to output JPEG data. Then it is a lot faster, and will produce better quality as a bonus, to replace your code with the following:

```
public void convert(String fileName , byte[] data) throws IOException {   
    File myFile =  new File(fileName);
    System.out.println("filename is " + file);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    try {
        out.write(data); // Just dump the database content to disk
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `image` object is `null`. I think there is no data in your `byte[] data` .

Change your if condition like below

```
if(imag != null)
{
    ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", myFile);
    System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
}else{
    System.out.println("imag is empty");
}
```

Comment: I have checked, the variable 'data' is not empty. I wrote in the question as well.